# RainTPL: It is possible to change the value of a variable after executing the draw method?

Tags: php, raintpl

I'm using RainTPL and I would like to know if it is possible to change the value of any variable after the draw () method

Today my meta tags are all static and I would like to make them dynamic, but my header.html template is called in my class's constructor method, and the data I would like to use in the meta tags is returned after that, in my routes.

In my constructor (Page.php) I have the following code:

```
$this->tpl->draw("page/header");
```

In my routes I have the following code:

```
$app->get("/products", function(){
    $products = Products::listAllProducts();
    $page = new Page();
    $page->setTpl("products/list", [
        "productsList"=>$products 
    ]);
});
```

I can pass the entire list of products to the list.html template, but I cannot pass some information to the header.html template because it has already been loaded in the constructor method.

So my meta tags are all static. Is there any way to change these values after the draw method?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no.

You could however include the header directly in your template. You will then be able to set variables in it at the same time as your main template. It could be an optional variable to not break compatibility with the rest of your application.